# cgroups: user.slice is missing

Tags: systemd, cgroups, debian-jessie

I am using a debian 8.7 (jessie) and have installed cgroups. It seems to work except that the user.slice is missing. I did not find out if there is a way to activate it.
I already tried to give it a config in the systemd directory (here for the user id 1000):

```
~# cat /etc/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/MemoryLimit.conf
[Slice]
MemoryLimit=67108864
```

systemd-cgls gives:

```
  ~# systemd-cgls
    ├─  1 /sbin/init
    ├─473 /sbin/cgmanager -m name=systemd
    └─system.slice
      ├─dbus.service
      │ └─478 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
      ├─cron.service
      │ └─474 /usr/sbin/cron -f
      ├─nfs-common.service
      │ ├─456 /sbin/rpc.statd
      │ └─470 /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
      ├─exim4.service
      │ └─740 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m
      ├─networking.service
      │ └─400 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
      ├─atd.service
      │ └─471 /usr/sbin/atd -f
      ├─systemd-journald.service
      │ └─176 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
      ├─ssh.service
      │ ├─ 472 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
      │ ├─1099 sshd: myuser [priv
      │ ├─1101 sshd: myuser@pts/1
      │ ├─1102 -bash
      │ ├─1113 sshd: root@pts/0    
      │ ├─1115 -bash
      │ ├─1153 systemd-cgls
      │ └─1154 pager
      ├─systemd-logind.service
      │ └─476 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
      ├─system-getty.slice
      │ └─getty@tty1.service
      │   └─503 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
      ├─systemd-udevd.service
      │ └─178 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
      ├─rpcbind.service
      │ └─441 /sbin/rpcbind -w
      ├─rdnssd.service
      │ ├─272 /sbin/rdnssd -u rdnssd -H /etc/rdnssd/merge-hook
      │ └─274 /sbin/rdnssd -u rdnssd -H /etc/rdnssd/merge-hook
      ├─rsyslog.service
      │ └─485 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
      └─acpid.service
        └─486 /usr/sbin/acpid
```

How can I enable user slices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself: I installed "libpam-systemd". This package contains the PAM module which registers user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy.